# .htaccess PHP - Prevent rewriting when only domain is entered

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site located at

```
application
  controllers
  views
  ...
  public <- the root of the site
    index.php <- entry point
    css
    ...
```

So the url is `http://localhost/application/public`. I would like when the user enters only `http://localhost/application/public` to do nothing except calling index.php without showing it.

Here are some examples:

`http://localhost/application/public` -> `http://localhost/application/public` or `http://localhost/application/public/`

BUT

`http://localhost/application/public/asdf` -> Rewrite internally to `http://localhost/application/public/index.php` and show only `http://localhost/application/public/asdf`

I have written the .htaccess. The only problem is that when entering `http://localhost/application/public` it opens `http://localhost/application/public/index.php` instead of `http://localhost/application/public`

One more thing - I want existing directories to be rewritten, so only existing files should not be rewritten to index.php So basically `http://localhost/application/public/css` should be rewritten to index.php. The reason I want this is to ommit the 403 Forbidden error, and kindly tell the user that the path does not exist.

**HTACCESS**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /application/public/

#Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#Do the rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

The reason I put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is to prevent `http://localhost/application/public` from rewriting. If `http://localhost/application/public` is rewritten, it loads `http://localhost/application/public/index.php`

Actually I know there are needed some modifications on `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. I want the root, **public** folder to not get rewritten, it should be the only exception. All of the rest physical folders like css, js, have to be rewritten, like not existing. Files should not be rewritten. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found a solution.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /application/public/

RewriteRule ^(css/?|js/?)$ index.php [NC,L] <- Folders css, js will be rewritten, but root directory won't be rewritten. Files inside them also won't be rewritten.

#Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#Do the rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```